# GAE Tutorial Exercise 1: Working With Entities - unknown error

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm attempting to do this tutorial: [GAE Tutorial 1](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise1.html).

When I try and deploy locally a window pops up telling me there are errors in my project, although it allows me to proceed anyway.  If I do proceed the application uploads, however, it doesn't perform correctly.

I get this error in the console twice:
May 15, 2012 2:55:00 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /favicon.ico

The app seems to work as normal though, however, when I try and click the 'add' button on the second tab this message appears in the console, and nothing else happens:

May 15, 2012 2:55:05 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /order

I could not find the errors, or find anything which told me where to find the errors.

Google allows you to download the completed code [here](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/download.jsp).  When I ran that, I got the same error.

I am pretty sure I set everything (Eclipse, GAE Plugin, and this particular tutorial) up correctly - I followed the online tutorials exactly.  I'm completely stumped.

Post Edit:

I have found a list of 21 Errors which all seem to relate to the WEB-INF/lib directory being empty.  They are all in the form:

The App Engine SDK JAR < appengine-api-1.0-skd-1.6.4.jar > is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory

with the part in the <> a bunch of different things which seem to be libraries(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Have you defined/added a "User Library" in your project build path, that points to your App Engine SDK libraries?[image]

2) Also, go to your Project -> Google -> App Engine Settings; there you can see if you have set the right App Engine SDKs ; appengine-api-1.0-skd-1.6.4.jar

3) Some projects also need ; gdata core and any other libraries such as Calendar or datanucleus...... If you are using any of those API